# How to renew git client on Ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu, heroku

Whenever I use `git` command, I get this warning:

**Your version of git is 1.9.1. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x**

But I have Ubuntu. I've tried running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, but it doesn't renew the git client version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```